# Error in making the build

Tags: iphone

I have prepared the build for the iPhone app that I have recently built.

The built had been successfully created but it is not being installed on my device.

I am not able to figure out the problem.

Can anyone please suggest me what might be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to give more details than this. What errors do you get?

Comment: This is not enough information to go by, maybe you can show an error message or what you tried doing?

Comment: Do you have a provisioning profile installed? Did you buy iOS Developer Program? Did you connect your device? Do you get any alerts/prompts/errors? We need more info! ;)

Comment: I had prepared the app.

It was running successfully on the simulator.

I then for the sake of testing on my device, prepared the build for the device.

The build was created successfully but is not being installed on the device.

Comment: the error while installing the app build is "A valid provisioning profile could not be found"

Comment: Do you have a paid account from Apple? Do you have the proper certificates and provisioning profiles?

Comment: the build was prepared on another mac and the device is connected to a different system.

Comment: Yes we have a paid Apple account....

Answer (score 3):

Since your error is

> A valid provisioning profile could not
>   be found

This means that you have not (correctly) installed a provisioning profile.

You cannot deploy an app onto a device without a valid provisioning profile. To obtain one, you must first register with Apple and pay them $99. Then you can create a profile through the developer portal and follow the detailed instructions to load the profile into Xcode, and subsequently install it and the app on the device.

Comment: What is:CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/ChineseTravelApp.app
cd "/Volumes/Data/CHINESE TRAVEL APP/ChineseTravelApp 2"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
/Volumes/Data/CHINESE TRAVEL APP/ChineseTravelApp 2/build/Debug-iphoneos/ChineseTravelApp.app: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: i am getting this error while preparing the build for the app...